# facebook sdk php get friends names

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I've already read about the new facebook sdk for php,
it talks about you cannot retrieve your friends information any more, and it saids about inviting friends, etc. 
But actually i used an app that gets some random friends names, and is not a game app,
I need exactly the same, random friend names, 
regards.

Comment: Apps that was created before 4/30/2014 could get all friends and they can do that until 4/30/2015. No app that was created after 4/30/2014 can access all friends. But depending on what you are doing using taggable_friends or social context api may work for you

Comment: I'm trying to use taggable_friends but I have a problem with the  version (taggable_friends requires version v2.0 or higher) im using version 2.0...

Answer (score 1):

There is a new API endpoint that can be used to get friend names. The new `/me/taggable_friends` friends API call is what you can use:

```
/v2.0/me/taggable_friends
```

The response will include friend names, profile picture and an encrypted ID that can be used with tagging API calls. [See the documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends).

Using the JS API, you can do something like:

```
FB.login(function(){
  FB.api('/me/taggable_friends', 'get', function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  } );
} );
```

Using PHP:

```
$taggable = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/taggable_friends' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $taggable, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

[See the full PHP example here](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/06/12/facebook-api-getting-friends-using-graph-api-2-0-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/).

You have to get this permission reviewed to use it with end-users. If you don't, you'll see a message like:

> (#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins,
>   developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be
>   reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review
>   please read our documentation on reviewable features:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

---

**EDIT**

To get larger profile images for friends, you need to use the `fields` parameter and request a specific type or size of image, e.g.:

```
/me/taggable_friends?fields=id,name,picture.type(large)
```

OR

```
/me/taggable_friends?fields=id,name,picture.width(500)
```

Using PHP:

```
$taggable = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/taggable_friends', [ 'fields' => 'id,name,picture.type(large)' ] ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $taggable, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Yep i'm trying to use taggable_friends but i have this problem:taggable_friends requires version v2.0 or higher where can i find an example of using v2.0?
im using  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"; and   FB.init({
    appId      : '446120005531689',
    
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });

Comment: You are already using the v2.0 JavaScript SDK. See where it says `version: 'v2.0'`.

Comment: Niraj Shah, it display an error, that is taggable friends are only for version 2.0 or after.

Comment: Must be a bug, as the code you are using is v2.0 code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include sample code for PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a way to get bigger profile picture of taggable friends? By default it gives picture of size  50px.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to get different sized images. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From v2.0 onwards; only the friends using the app that is requesting can be fetched with [`{user-id}/friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends).

Using the same API with v1.0 was able to fetch all the friends list. But this version will be removed after April 30, 2015. [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions)

Comment: Yep i'm trying to use taggable_friends but i have this problem:taggable_friends requires version v2.0 or higher

Comment: So what happens when you call `v2.0/taggable_friends` ? if you're using v1.0 you can just fetch the friends list as before: `/<user>/friends`

Comment: Igy, no you cant call friends any more, only lists the friends that are using the app